# React re-use a component with different style and layout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, react-css-modules

I'm new to styling in React. I tried CSS modules and styled components but I'm not able to change layout and styles.

The goal is to have a group of buttons to display as flex on the main page and as an inline with different style attributes in another page by re-using the **HomeButtons.js** component.

**HomeButtons.js** is the home page and it has a map() function looping through a button called **ButtonCategory.js**.
**HomeButtons.js** renders the map() inside a styled  using CSS modules file. **ButtonCategory** is styled with a CSS modules file as well.

**HomeButtons.js** is then returned inside a  in another class Component called **CardsCategory.js**. It is in this component that I'm trying to change the display and styl... With a styled Component on the  I can show a border but the display attribute doesn't works.With **CardsCategory.module.css** I can't change the display either...

Not sure what to do... How to change the layout of the re-used component and the style of its nested button component ?

Any feedback is welcome!

**HomeButtons.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import classes from './HomeButtons.module.css';
import ButtonCategory from '../../components/ButtonCategory/ButtonCategory'

class HomeButtons extends Component {

    handleClick = (buttonValue) => {
        buttonValue = buttonValue.slice(0, 3).toLowerCase();
        this.props.history.push("/" + buttonValue);
    };
    render() {
        const allCategoriesButtons = ["Physics", "Chemistry", "Medicine", "Literature", "Peace", "Economics"];
        const allCatMap = allCategoriesButtons.map(button =>
            < ButtonCategory
                key={button.toString()}
                value={button}
                name={button}
                onClick={e => this.handleClick(e.target.value)}
            />
        )

        return (
            <div>
                <div className={classes.container__section}>
                    {allCatMap}
                </div >
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default HomeButtons;
```

***HomeButtons.module.css***

```
.container__section {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    margin: auto;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

**ButtonCategory**

```
import React from 'react'
import classes from  './ButtonCategory.module.css';

function buttonCategory(props) {

    return (
        <button
         className={classes.b}
            name={props.name}
            onClick={props.onClick}
            value={props.value}
        >
            {props.name}
        </button>
    )
}

export default buttonCategory;
```

***ButtonCategory.module.css***

```
    opacity: 0.5;
    color: red;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    flex: 1 400px;
    height: 3em;
}
```

**CardsCategory**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import classes from './CardsCategory.module.css';
import HomeButtons from "../HomeButtons/HomeButtons"
import styled from 'styled-components';


const StyledDiv = styled.div`
border: 10px solid orange;
//display: inline; //NOT working
`

class Cards extends Component {
    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <StyledDiv> 
                    <HomeButtons className={classes.test}/>
                </StyledDiv>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Cards;
```

**CardsCategory.module.css**

```
.test {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send styles thru the props and in the component set them as your styles ex.

```
<MyComponent textAlign='center' ...>
```

in MyComponent component

```
<div style={{textAlign: this.props.textAlign}}>
    ...
</div>
```

or send whole styles as objects ex.

```
render(){
    const stl = {textAlign: 'center',width:'500px'};
    return(
        <MyComponent wholeStyle={stl}/>
    )
}
```

and in MyComponent

```
<div style={this.props.wholeStyle}>
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

They are 3 ways you can style through props

1. You can pass an entire style object

Eg:

<MappedComponent style={'display':'flex','alignItems':'center'} />

In the mapped component

Function MappedComponent ({style}){
return (

What's popaining !

);
}

2. You can style by passing in the specific style you want

Eg:

<MappedComponent textAlign={'center'} />

In the mapped component

Function MappedComponent ({textAlign}){
return (

What's popaining !

);
}

3. The third way you can style is by defining styles in a CSS file and just passing in the class name

Eg:

<MappedComponent className={''flex-button-style'} />

In the mapped component

Function MappedComponent ({className}){
return (

What's popaining !

);
}

Pick what works best for you and stay consistent with it :) .